# strongSwan without password on iOS

Tags: ios, vpn

I have the following problem: I need to authenticate on VPN with iOS without password, but with certificate only. The reason is I need "VPN on demand", which is active on certificate authentication only.

I found [this tutorial](http://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/IOS_%28Apple%29#Certificate-requirements-for-iOS-interoperability), but it uses certificate+password authentication. But I need certificate only. I've been trying to remove xauth authentication from config, but I failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I [asked the same question on Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/476033/strongswan-without-password-on-ios), and got [an answer from ecdsa](https://serverfault.com/a/476114):

> The iPhone VPN client does not allow a configuration without XAuth (at
> least not in the graphical configuration interface). Luckily, it
> doesn't mind if the VPN gateway simply concludes the expected XAuth
> exchange without actually requesting any user credentials.  I recently
> created [a patch for strongSwan 5.0.2](http://git.strongswan.org/?p=strongswan.git;a=commitdiff;h=e4013bb90404aea5728bca9da9ae71abcbd935ea) that adds a plugin that
> allows to configure this kind of XAuth "authentication".  With the
> patch applied you can configure
>
> ```
> leftauth=rsa
> rightauth=rsa
> rightauth2=xauth-noauth
> ```
>
> in ipsec.conf to essentially use only RSA authentication.
>
> **Update:** The *xauth-noauth* plugin has been released with strongSwan 5.0.3.